# How to download Dynamics AX 2012 for windows 8.1

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

**I am a fresher** and i am working on dynamics AX 2012, and i need the steps how to download and install ***Dynamics AX 2012*** in ***windows 8.1***

Comment: Note that the [system requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11094) do not list Windows 8.1 as a supported OS (at least not for the server components).

Answer (score 2):

For download you must decidde between **R**elease version:

- RTM (https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/northamerica/AX/downloads/service-packs/MicrosoftDynamicsAX2012RTM)
- R2 (https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/northamerica/AX/downloads/service-packs/MicrosoftDynamicsAX2012R2)
- R3 (https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/northamerica/AX/downloads/product-releases/MSDYAX2012R3Release)

Then follow [Installation guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12687).

Comment: But i am having problem accessing Customer Source

Comment: Needless to say, use R3 if possible!

Comment: Or even AX7 / Dynamics 365 for Operations Enterprise